# Transferring / reinstalling Magento on server

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1

I've tried for hours to get Magento running on my webspace, but it just doesn't work.

I already have it running locally with xampp and everything seems to work fine.

When I upload the files and the database and change the mysql connection data and the base url in the db, I get the index page without proper style and formatting and without images and the links don't work, I always get a 404 error.

I tried to reinstall by deleting the appropriate files, but somehow I get either a database connection error or the error message that says invalid url. The index page was able to connect and I know the connection information is right.

Has anyone an idea what the problem might be or where to look for further information?
Here's the phpinfo() output: http://gyazo.com/300e884f8837bc98f64474695f5974d0

Comment: Check the rendered source for your homepage. Where are the URLs for the CSS pointing?

Comment: .htaccess in  root folder ?

Answer (score 2):

1) [Turn on Developer Mode on your remote instance](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7).

2) Make sure you aren't uploading transient files (i.e. the transferred `./var/` should contain nothing).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've tried another upload and it seems to work better if I replace every occurence of "localhost" in the sql file before upload, rather than just changing the 2 values in the configuration table as stated in one of the instructions. Now I still have the problem with the url-rewriting. I only get 404 pages when it's activated. I already tried to alter my .htaccess file accordingly and I know that the server supports url rewriting. Any Ideas?

Comment: *"it seems to work better if I replace every occurence of "localhost" in the sql file before upload"* is a scary statement. What do you mean?? Regarding rewrites & 404 you need to make sure that your remote config is set correctly for that server's settings. Also, make sure that you are including .htaccess from the root folder.