# Magento transferred to Local returning 500 attempting to install error

Tags: magento-1.9, windows, transfer, mamp

I'm attempting to duplicate a live site I'm working on to my local windows environment for testing. I'm using MAMP PRO to run the db.

I'm getting this 500 error:

> The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php/install/. It may be down for
>   maintenance or configured incorrectly.

What I've done so far:

1. Copied all my production files to local (using our git repo)
2. Dumped my magento production db and imported it into my mamp db
3. Edited app/etc/local.xml file and changed database info
4. In local mySQL edited the two core_config_data table entries
5. Deleted my cache
6. Set permissions for my entire local environment to be read & write (using windows folder permissions as chmod is not available on windows I believe)

After doing all that, I'm still getting the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Enable error reporting in your installation. Your server should through the raw errors in that case which would be much better to understand.

Comment: How do I enable error reporting when I can't get the magento site to come up?

Comment: Error reporting is enabled via index.php file, not through site. Check this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7