# Magento 1.9 set mode in nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

How do I set modes to `production` or `default` or `developer` in my nginx conf file?

I need to do this for Magento 1.9 version and not Magento 2

Comment: @MagenX I need it for magento 1.9 and not magento 2

Comment: what exactly you need to achieve???

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7

Comment: In 1.x there is only developer mode.