# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/Mage.php:463

Tags: magento-1.9, error, installation

I am installing my team's installation of Magento on my developer machine, and I am getting this error message when I try to go to the frontend root or the /admin of the website:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/Mage.php:463

Stack trace:

#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(919): Mage::getModel('core/store')
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(834): Mage_Core_Model_App->_getDefaultStore()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/Mage.php(920): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/Mage.php(702): Mage::printException(Object(Mage_Core_Exception))
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') #5 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wt/app/Mage.php on line 463
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I resolved this on the fly, and I had a similar problem with another function - and also getting the "Call to a member function getModelInstance() on null in...." error message. I resolved it by creating var and media folders (for some reason I didn't have them), and putting 777 permissions on them.

Answer (score 0):

This error is tricky. Magento has thrown some exception and tries to print it but then runs into another error. Now we don't know what the original exception was, only that it occured very early, before the config model has been initialized, judging by the error message.

But there is a way to make Magento actually print the exception on the screen without trying to load anything additionally: **enable developer mode**

See: [How to enable Developer Mode in Magento 1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15482/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-magento-1-7)

Comment: I tried setting the Magento developer mode, and theproblem is still there, and I don't see much more than I did prior to this change.